# Can Capistrano only move new files?

Tags: file, synchronization, capistrano

This is not a ruby/rails project deploy. I have the following situation and I would like to know if Capistrano can solve my problem, or if you know something more proper.

- A host **Windows** machine, with ruby installed and capistrano.
- This machine have some files in a folder, that will be updated (all or just some).
- The goal is to sync the updated files with many other servers.

Some considerations:

1) These files can be big (> 100MB), so I wouldn't like to send all files to everyone every time. Things that didn't change wasn't supposed to be sent again.

2) A distributed deploy would be a plus. Let's suppose I have a host machine and 100 endpoints, making these endpoints serve one to another after syncing would be something really good.

3) Maybe there are some servers that doesn't need all files.

4) There's no code at all, maybe no command line need also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capistrano can isn't just for ruby/rails and can move non-new files.  You can use it with, say, rsync.  Check out this SO answer:

[Using Capistrano to deploy (a non-Rails site) via FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327417/using-capistrano-to-deploy-a-non-rails-site-via-ftp)

Comment: Use DeltaCopy or run rsync under cygwin.  I've heard, but never tried, to run the cygwin rsync without completely installing cygwin.  As always, ymmv.